Checking all values in a row of a df
I have a data frame and I wish to create a new data frame of this data based on the values in each row. Here I am trying to keep any rows in my data where there are no 'Unknown' values in any of the columns.
mydf
name   age      height    job      city
Dave   54       180        Y      London
John   Unknown  Unknown  Unknown  Unknown
Steve  34       182       Y       Birmingham
Mark    38      178       Y       Unknown

What I am trying to achieve;
mynewdf
name   age      height   job     city
Dave   54       180       Y      London
Steve  34       182       Y      Birmingham

I've tried to subset my data using which and all functions but I seem to be using the all incorrectly.

I recommend mydf[mydf=="Unknown"]=NA; mydf=mydf[complete.cases(mydf), ] If you do not like changing "Unknown" to NA, you might want to do: mydf=mydf[!rowSums(mydf=="Unknown"), ]. There is no need for external packages. Your question is close to duplicates.

df[apply(df, 1, \(x) !any(x == "Unknown"), simplify = TRUE), ]

dplyr allows you to use if_any for filtering - https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- tibble(
  name = c("Dave", "John", "Steve", "Mark"),
  age = c(54L, "Unknown", 34L, 38L),
  height = c(180, "Unknown", 182, 178),
  job = c("Y", "Unknown", "Y", "Y"),
  city = c("London", "Unknown", "Birmingham", "Unknown")
)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(stringr::str_to_lower(.x) == "unknown", NA, .x))) %>% 
  filter(!if_any(everything(), is.na))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   name  age   height job   city      
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 Dave  54    180    Y     London    
#> 2 Steve 34    182    Y     Birmingham

Created on 2024-09-17 with reprex v2.1.1

This is an uncommon, comparatively  slow, and external approach for a simple task which can be done much better in base R.

@Friede I'm not sure how common or uncommon it is, I just think the syntax is simple to read. If the question led me to believe there was an emphasis on performance I'd do benchmarking and post the most performant solution I could find. The question didn't though, and at least for me, the tidyverse syntax is easier / faster to work with.

or filter(my_df, if_all(everything(), `!=`, "Unknown"))

or mydf[!rowSums(mydf == "Unknown"),] in base R
